# how to find mail that was send by MailItem.Display()

Tags: c#, winforms, email, outlook

I have following requirement :

- Allow the user to drag & drop an email from outlook to a datagrid
- Prepare a reply mail, and show it so the user can review and send
- After sending, also fetch the send mail and put it into the datagrid

The drag/drop I have working
Preparing the replay email and showing it to the user I also have working, with this code :

```
MailItem mail = GetMailBySubject(dateReceived, subject);
if (mail != null)
{
    MailItem mailReply = mail.ReplyAll();
    // add text and stuff to mailReply...
    mailReply.Display();
}
```

This will open a window in outlook, as if the user clicked reply in outlook.

Now I am stuck with the 3th requirement,
after the user send the reply email, I need somehow to find this email in outlook to add it to my datagrid.

But I have no clue on how to do that.
All I have is the original mail that is been used to prepare the reply.
Is there a way to find the reply with only this, or is this maybe a complete wrong approach ?
To make it more difficult is that I have to show the reply email NON Modal, so I have no trigger when the user clicked on send in outlook.

for reference, here is the code for GetMailBySubject

```
private MailItem GetMailBySubject(DateTime dateReceived, string subject)
{
    MailItem Result = null;

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application OutlookIns = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace olNamespace = OutlookIns.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    MAPIFolder myInbox = olNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

    Items items = myInbox.Items;
    int count = items.Count;
    MailItem mail = null;
    int i = 1; //DO NOT START ON 0

    while ((i < count) && (Result == null))
    {
        if (items[i] is MailItem)
        {
            mail = (MailItem)items[i];
            if ((mail.ReceivedTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss") == dateReceived.ToString("yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss")) && (mail.Subject == subject))
            {
                Result = mail;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }

    return Result;
}
```

**EDIT**
I tried this code as suggested, but the `Items.ItemAdd` event is not firing.
So I must still be doing something wrong but I cant see it

this is my code now

```
MailItem mail = GetMailBySubject((DateTime)sentOn, msg.Subject);
if (mail != null)
{
    MailItem mailReply = mail.ReplyAll();
    mailReply.HTMLBody = GetDefaultReplyText() + Environment.NewLine + mailReply.HTMLBody;

    Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
    UserProperties mailUserProperties = null;
    UserProperty mailUserProperty = null;

    mailUserProperties = mailReply.UserProperties;
    mailUserProperty = mailUserProperties.Add("myproperty", OlUserPropertyType.olText);
    mailUserProperty.Value = guid.ToString(); ;
    // the code below gives error "The property cannot be parsed or has an invalid format"
    //mailReply.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("myproperty", guid.ToString());

    mailReply.Display();
}


private MailItem GetMailBySubject(DateTime dateReceived, string subject)
{
    MailItem Result = null;

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application OutlookIns = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace olNamespace = OutlookIns.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    MAPIFolder myInbox = olNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

    Items items = myInbox.Items;
    int count = items.Count;
    MailItem mail = null;
    int i = 1; //DO NOT START ON 0

    while ((i < count) && (Result == null))
    {
        if (items[i] is MailItem)
        {
            mail = (MailItem)items[i];
            if ((mail.ReceivedTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss") == dateReceived.ToString("yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss")) && (mail.Subject == subject))
            {
                Result = mail;
                MAPIFolder mySent = olNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail);
                mySent.Items.ItemAdd += Items_SentMailItemAdd;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    return Result;
}
```

and finally

```
private void Items_SentMailItemAdd(object Item)
{
    //throw new NotImplementedException();
    ; // this event is never fired
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Items.ItemAdd` event on the Sent Items folder. To check if that is your message, set a custom property on the message that you create and display. You can use `MailItem.UserProperties.Add`, but that can force the message to be sent in the TNEF format. To prevent that from happening, you can use `MailItem.PropertyAccessro.SetProperty` to set a named MAPI property without using the `UserProperties` collection. You can set a test user property and look at its DASL name (to be used by `SetProperty`) with OutlookSpy (I am its author - select the message, click IMessage button, select your custom property, see the DASL edit box).

Comment: thank you, I am trying this but I get error `The property "myproperty" cannot be parsed or has an invalid format` I tried like this `mailReply.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("myproperty", guid);` where guid is ` Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();`

Comment: I can set the property now, but the event is never fired. I put all my code in the edit on my answer. Maybe you can see what I missed ?

Comment: See my reply to your original question.

Comment: do you mean using `MailItem.PropertiesAcces.SetProperty` ? I cant get that working it keeps returning error "The property cannot be parsed or has invalid format."

Comment: Do you specify the property name in the DASL format? Did you look at the existing properties with OutlookSpy to see what that format is?

Comment: how to find the userproperty "myproperty" in this outlookspy ?

Comment: Set the property programmatically using OOM. Select that message in Outlook. Click IMessage button on the OutlookSpy ribbon.Select the property, look at the DASL edit box.

Comment: sorry to bother you so often, but what is OOM ? I am new to outlook programming

Comment: OOM=Outlook Object Model

Comment: Do you have some code example on how to set the property using OOM

Comment: MailItem.UserPorperties.Add(...) / MailItem.Save

Comment: Then you should be able to see the property and its DASL name in OutlookSpy.

Comment: Are you looking at the message with that property set?